# Change map projection in Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, wgs84, vue.js

[image: Current projection]I'm using leaflet in my current project. As a map sourse Leaflet consumes json-file with coordinates in WGS84 EPSG 4326.

```
     <l-map
      ref="myMap"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      :options="options"
    >
import regionsGJ from './geojson/geojson_wgs84.js'
import districtsGJ from './geojson/geojson_district.js'
import { LMap, LGeoJson, LCircleMarker } from 'vue2-leaflet'

export default {
  name: 'LeafletMap',
  components: {
    LMap,
    LGeoJson,
    LCircleMarker
  },
  data () {
    return {
      map: undefined,
      zoom: 3,
      center: [65.9034, 89.4203],
      fillColor: '#9aabff',
      orderFillColor: '#3f60ff',
      districts: Object.freeze(districtsGJ),
      options: {
        zoomControl: false,
        zoomDelta: 0.25,
        zoomSnap: 0,
        maxZoom: 7,
        minZoom: 2.25
      }
    }
  },
     

    type: 'FeatureCollection', name: 'geojson_wgs84', crs: { type: 'name', properties: { name: 'urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84' } }, features: [{ type: 'Feature', properties: { Name: 'Adygea', icon: null, enName: 'The Republic of Adygea', fullName: 'Republic Adygea', guid: null, id: 1, created: '2015-04-20T13:08:26', geoCode: 'RU-AD' }, geometry: { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [[[39.690642582355224, 45.190079106147344],
```

I need to change the appearance of the map - show it in another projection. What steps I have to produce? Do I need to convert existing json-file to another CRS? Should it be strictly with lot/lang coordinates or Leaflet can work with projected coordiantes (like meters etc)?
Or maybe it is possible to change some settings in Leaflet to change map's appearance?

[image: Desired projection]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the appearance of the map"?

Comment: I need to change visual appearance of the map: show it in another projection.

Comment: See example of setting CRS: https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/examples/custom-crs.html